# How to sort array in ng-options by key?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, angularjs-filter, angularjs-ng-options

There is such array:

```
month: Array[13]0: "M"1: "January"2: "February"3: "March"4: "April"5: "May"6: "June"7: "July"8: "August"9: "September"10: "October"11: "November"12: "December"
```

I do:

```
ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in data.month | orderBy:key"
```

But I get unsorted select list.

Comment: The array is already in calendar order, why are you sorting it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In order to use tracking with filters use `track by`.

**Markup**

```
ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in data.month | orderBy:'key' track by key"
```

**Update**

This `orderBy` will never work because you are having literal array. You need to convert this array to JSON like object which would structured like `[{id: 0, value: "M"}, {id: 1, value: "January"},......]`

**HTML**

```
ng-options="item.id as item.value for items in data.month | orderBy:'id'"
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ho4ZL1btD5xJYUso3S19?p=preview)

Comment: I get empty select list by your solution

Comment: @Faud try adding single `'` on key as @solid_luffy said

Comment: Also is same. Not working. I get error: Error: $parse:lexerr
Lexer Error

Comment: I have format : `"day":[{"id":1,"value":1},{"id":2,"value":2}` but get empty list with error: `Error: [$parse:lexerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unterminated%20quote&p1=s%203-4%20%5B'%5D&p2=key'`

Comment: @Faud could you accept mine answer..I'll give you working fiddle/plunkr

Comment: @Faud check the plunkr which I've added..Thanks

Comment: The plunkr is an `ng-repeat`; similar but not what this question asks.  Also did you mean `item.id as item.value for items` in your html template snippet or `item.id as item.value for item` (no `s` on final `item`)?

Answer (score 2):

Your missing two `'`'s. This part, `orderBy: key` should be `orderBy:'key'`

Try this:

```
ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in data.month | orderBy: 'key'"
```

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue need reformat `ng-option` like as:

```
day.id as day.value for day in data.month
```

And array `data.month` would be how as told user `pankajparkar`