# orderBy value in Angular comprehension_expression

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I would like to order the `<option>`s of a `<select>` by the **values** of an object, using `ng-options`.

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.people = {'A1': 'Adam Smith', 'A2': 'Adam Adams'};
}


<select ng-model="selected"
  ng-options="name for (userid, name) in people | orderBy:'name'"
></select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9k1686jt/

However, the `orderBy` filter doesn't seem to have any effect.

**Expected output**:

```
...
<option ...>Adam Adams</option>
<option ...>Adam Smith</option>
...
```

**Actual output**:

```
...
<option ...>Adam Smith</option>
<option ...>Adam Adams</option>
...
```

How can I use `ng-options` to produce the Expected output?

I'm using Angular 1.3

Comment: Your example doesn't have a `name` property to use the orderBy filter, so it just defaults to the original list (which has Adam Smith first).

This fiddle works: http://jsfiddle.net/naetrz0g/

Comment: You could consider reform your JSON and then use `orderBy` filter like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30621111/2435473)